# How to use a DTO and Messenger with Api-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

For one of our resources, we'd like to route the request through a command handler. Creating a new item for this resource has a number of side-effects and prior requirements, so regular REST is not enough.

Since we already have a Messenger handler written for use in different parts of the application, and a simple command object, we thought to use Messenger with an Input Object, as [described in the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/#using-messenger-with-an-input-object), that says:

> Set the `messenger` attribute to `input`, and API Platform will automatically dispatch the given Input as a message instead of the Resource. Indeed, it'll add a default `DataTransformer` (see input/output documentation) that handles the given `input`

My resource is described thus:

```
App\Domain\Entity\Bid:
  input: 'App\Application\Command\Lead\BidOnLead'
  messenger: "input"
  itemOperations:
    get: ~
  collectionOperations:
    get: ~
    post: ~
```

But, when I load the api-docs the schema I'm shown as input is the schema for `App\Domain\Entity\Bid`, not the schema for `App\Application\Command\Lead\BidOnLead`, as I would expect.

In case it was only a matter of the documentation being generated incorrectly, I've tried sending a JSON describing the input object (it's a very simple object with a couple of properties), but it fails because it's trying to deserialize into the resource object, not into the input object.

What I'm doing wrong, and how can I implement this?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but per documentation here:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/#symfony-messenger-integration-cqrs-and-async-message-processing

`input` should be under `attributes` key:

```
App\Domain\Entity\Bid:
    attributes:
        input: 'App\Application\Command\Lead\BidOnLead'
        messenger: "input"
    itemOperations:
        get: ~
    collectionOperations:
        get: ~
        post: ~
```

It may be misleading if you just copying things from annotations to yaml as documentation for yaml is not thorough in ApiPlatform.